# Changing the back-color of the cmd window in C?

Tags: c, backcolor

Is there a way to change the black background of the *cmd* window that open when

running the function to another color?

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16815/how-to-personalize-the-windows-command-prompt/

Comment: of the **function**

Comment: [Read about the Windows console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: and the **background**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on top bar of cmd then click properties then go to Colors tab and select your color then ok.

#Edited

use `system(color 17);`

it will give you white font on blue background. here `1` for blue and `7` for white. remember first code for background color and second code for font color.

here is some color codes.

```
A = Light Green     
B = Light Aqua 
C = Light Red 
D = Light Purple 
E = Light Yellow
F = Bright White
0 = Black 
1 = Blue   
2 = Green 
3 = Aqua
4 = Red
5 = Purple
6 = Yellow
7 = White 
8 = Gray    
9 = Light Blue
```

Comment: I mean to a code that do that.

Comment: like the function that change the text-color.

Comment: for the background-color

Comment: `system(color 17);` it will give you white font on blue background. here 1 for blue and 7 for white. remember first code for background color and second code for font color. here is color codes `0 = Black   8 = Gray
1 = Blue    9 = Light Blue
2 = Green   A = Light Green
3 = Aqua    B = Light Aqua
4 = Red     C = Light Red
5 = Purple  D = Light Purple
6 = Yellow  E = Light Yellow
7 = White   F = Bright White`

Answer (score 2):

On **Windows** this can be done with an easy system call.

```
system("color <hexval><hexval>");
```

For example:

```
system("color 0a");
```

will change the background colour to black, and the foreground colour to green.

By opening a command prompt in Windows, you can type "color", and it will output all the possible variations. Then just try them out and implement it in your code.

Comment: thanks. I will try ASAP.

Comment: If my answer helped you, considering accepting it as the answer. That way it's easier for others to find.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
color
```

command in cmd.

```
color
```

command takes one argument in which first character corresponds to background and second character corresponds to foreground. Provide the character in HEX format.

```
0=BLACK  1=BLUE
2=GREEN  3=AQUA
4=RED  5=PURPLE
6=YELLOW  7=WHITE
8=GRAY  9=LIGHT BLUE
A=LIGHT GREEN  B=LIGHT AQUA
C=LIGHT RED  D=LIGHT PURPLE
E=LIGHT YELLOW  F=BRIGHT WHIT
```

for more help You can type

```
`color /?`
```

in command Prompt
Thanks